Apache: Serving "core" files between different domains AND unique files to each domain
Server: Ubuntu/Apache
Scenario  I have a system that is used by different domains  
I would like the "core" files to be used for all domains (to make maintenance easier)  
However, each domain must have some of its own/exclusive directories
Example:  
Core Files (all filetypes - accessed by domainA, domainB, etc.)  
/var/www/corefiles
Exclusive files for each domain (read and write permission)  
/var/www/domainA 
/var/www/domainB 
I thought about trying to solve this with vhosts:  
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainA.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domainA

  <Directory /var/www/domainA>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  
  Alias ​​/corefiles /var/www/corefiles

  <Directory /var/www/corefiles>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Logs
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domainA_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domainA_access.log combined

  # SSL
  SSLEngine on SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainA.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainA.com.key

  # TMP files
  php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/domainA/tmp"
</VirtualHost>

And in the config file in each domain:
define('DOMAIN', 'https://domainA/');
define('APPLICATION', '/var/www/corefiles');
define('FILES', '/var/www/domainA/files');

Is this possible?  
Any security issues?  
Any questions about SSL certificates, cookies, PHP temp files, etc?  
Any other suggestions?
Thanks

Or... how do WordPress, Wix, Shopify, etc. - and all other hosted solutions - update core files/versions all at once?
